# Switch Bluetooth mode to HID

Tags: keyboard, 15.04, mouse, bluetooth

I am trying to connect a wireless Logitech MX5000 keyboard and a MX1000 mouse. At the moment, they are connected via Bluetooth as HCI, but I have learnt that if they are connected in HID mode, they can work on boot and I can use KeyTouch editor to map missing media keys.

I used to have a Logitech BT dongle, the type that had a red connection button at the back, which made the selection of mode very easy. But this broke down and now have to use a new CSR dongle. How can I switch the default HCI connection to HID via GUI or command line? Apparently there was a BlueZ command called hci2hid but I can't see it in Vivid (bluez 4.101-0ubuntu25).
If anyone knows how to switch modes, I'll be very grateful.
Thanks.

Comment: I cant get it to work in 15.10 even with the dongle. It used to be that you would need to edit the rules in /lib/udev/rules.d/62-bluez-hid2hci.rules but that set of rules doesnt exist anymore